# How to run owsap zap automatically using command line operations(i.e. Jenkins)

Tags: owasp

I have tried few ways as below :-

using API as below :-

https://www.securify.nl/blog/SFY20150303/automating-security-tests-using-owasp-zap-and-jenkins.html

But getting error as below :-

[Getting error in python code for automate owsap zap for the application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45566018/getting-error-in-python-code-for-automate-owsap-zap-for-the-application)

I have tried with zapr

https://github.com/garethr/zapr

it's also showing error as set path while I have try to set it by every possible combination.

You have any way and their steps/ tutorial (link, video) so I can achieve same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The new script and dependencies are present in below URL:-

https://github.com/zaproxy/zaproxy/wiki/ApiPython

Replace the changeMe apikey to zap apikey. You will find it in Tools -> options -> API.