# How to create HTML report for zap(Owasp) using Python API script which integrates with Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, owasp, zap

I have trigger zap with Python API as below:-

Script source:-

https://github.com/zaproxy/zaproxy/wiki/ApiPython

I want an HTML report generated via command line.

I am trying to integrate same with Jenkins.
I have found few plug-ins of Owasp in Jenkins but doesn't seem to work as expected.

Any idea, link, tutorials will really help me.

Comment: http://localhost:8080/OTHER/core/other/htmlreport/?apikey=mykey&formMethod=GET will show the report. but how to save and send it with Jenkins refer :- https://github.com/zaproxy/zaproxy/issues/2920

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At this URL/API ( http://ZAP-IP:PORT/UI/core/other/htmlreport/) user can get the report.

I havn't found any zap support plug-in so I have wrote selenium webdriver java script to accomplish my task. The code is :-

```
    @Test
    public void Report() {
            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",System.getProperty("user.dir")+"\\src\\lib\\chromedriver.exe");
            ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
            chromeOptions.addArguments("--start-maximized");
            WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);
            driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            driver.get("http://localhost:8080/UI/core/other/htmlreport");
            driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            driver.findElement(By.id("apikey")).sendKeys("ChangeMe");
            driver.findElement(By.id("button")).click();

            SimpleDateFormat dateFormatForFoldername = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm-ss");
            Date currentDate = new Date();
            String folderDateFormat = dateFormatForFoldername.format(currentDate);
        try {
            URL oracle = new URL(driver.getCurrentUrl());
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(oracle.openStream()));
            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("Reports"+File.separator+"OwaspReport-"+folderDateFormat+".html"));

            String inputLine;
            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null){
                try{
                    writer.write(inputLine);
                }
                catch(IOException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    return;
                }
            }
            in.close();
            writer.close();
            driver.quit();
        }
        catch(Exception ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }   
    }
```

Note :- change the port in URL as per your zap port and replace the apiKey

Hope it will help you :)

Answer (score 0):

I found the python API would only connent to local zaproxy server, so jenkins slave and zaproxy server should be running in the same machine(pod).

I use jenkins pipeline and the publishHTML plugin to integrate report to jenkins result.

1. generate a report file in jenkins slave machine by python script

   ```
   fHTML=open('/zap/report/zapreport.html', 'w')
   fHTML.write(zap.core.htmlreport())
   fHTML.close()
   ```
2. publish the report to jenkins result

   ```
         sh "cp /zap/report/* ./report"
         publishHTML (target: [
           allowMissing: false,
           alwaysLinkToLastBuild: false,
           keepAll: true,
           reportDir: 'report',
           reportFiles: 'zapreport.html',
           reportName: "Zaproxy Report"
         ])
   ```